# Display list of usercontrols within itemtemplate next to other controls

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, user-controls, listbox

I would like to display a list of usercontrols binded to a listbox

next to each usercontrol there should be a button

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding usercontrollist}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <!--usercontrol of the current binded items-->
                <Button Content="x" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

How can i do this in xaml code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `usercontrollist` is a collection of `UserControl`, then you should be able to do this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
```